# java delete column from primary key that start with?

Tags: java, sql-server

ok iam having a problem i need to delete all columns that start with ? on primery key ex.?5 ,?4 i amm running this throw a java app i have build so i need the java query that search my database ektupotiko and then delete all columns that start  with  ? on primary key

here is my try but it doesnt work any idea how i can make it work ?

```
 public void mix(){
String queryy ="DELETE  FROM ektupotiko WHERE Αριθμος_ΔΔΥ = ?% ");
      executeSQLQueryy(queryy,"updated");
}

     public void  executeSQLQueryy (String queryy,String message) {
            Connection con =getConnection();
            Statement st;
            try{
                st =con.createStatement();
                if((st.executeUpdate(queryy))==1)
                {
                   con.commit(); 

                  // DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)jTable_ProSales.getModel();
                   // model.setRowCount(0);
                   //show_Basket_in_Jtable();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data "+message+" Succefully");
                }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data "+message+ " Succefully");
                }

                    }catch (Exception ex){
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }}
```

Comment: you are missing the '?%' for ?% I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is looking for equality and also is missing some quotes, try with a `LIKE` clause :

```
String queryy = "DELETE  FROM ektupotiko WHERE Αριθμος_ΔΔΥ LIKE '?%' ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `like` :

```
  String queryy ="DELETE FROM ektupotiko WHERE Αριθμος_ΔΔΥ like '?%' ";
  executeSQLQueryy(queryy, "updated");
```

Comment: String queryy ="DELETE FROM ektupotiko WHERE Αριθμος_ΔΔΥ like '?%' )"; 
  executeSQLQueryy(queryy,"updated");

Comment: i run it but he say com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: so what a have to do ?